# Why do CoMarshalInterface and CoUnmarshalInterface need REFIID?

Tags: c++, com, marshalling, unmarshalling, ole

I am a noob regarding COM. In the project that I am currently working we use `CoMarshalInterface` and `CoUnmarshalInterface` with `REFIID` of `IDispatch` for all the COM object/proxy instances because they are all derived from it.

I wanted to template the code and use it with the most derived COM interfaces and that sparked a discussion in the team as it might introduce unintended/unforeseen changes. From testing, I did not see any differences, but it's still a bit curious that these functions need a `REFIID` parameter.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Why do `CoMarshalInterface` and `CoUnmarshalInterface` need the `REFIID` parameter? In the docs [1] MS says they query the object for `IMarshal` and if not found they fallback to the default COM implementation
2. Is there any difference between calling these functions with `IDispatch` vs most derived interfaces (which we know are derived from `IDispatch`)? The scenario put forward was maybe some interfaces do implement `IMarshal`, but the implementations might have problems. In that case, wouldn't the object reply to the `QueryInterface` with `IMarshal` regardless of the functions being called with `IDispatch` or most derived?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-comarshalinterface#remarks

Comment: I'm curious why you need these calls in the first place? Working with IDispatch-type interfaces usually means you have MIDL and/or a type library somewhere and when you only use methods in this type lib, you have nothing to explicitly un/marshal. Also why do you need to implement IMarshal, this adds another level of complexity?

Comment: Marshaling works by creating a proxy and stub.  Interfaces that look exactly like the original interface but whose implementation methods actually de/serialize the function arguments so that the original function can execute on a different thread or process or machine.  Necessarily that requires knowing what specific interface needs to be marshalled.  When you marshal IDispatch then you get a proxy and stub that *only* marshal IDispatch functions, not any derived interface.  Using CoMarshalInterface() or IMarshal is not terribly common, IGlobalInterfaceTable is very convenient.

Comment: @SimonMourier We use them to be able to pass COM pointers between threads. We don't need to implement `IMarshal`, but wondering what happens if some of those interfaces do and if anything would change between using `IDispatch` vs the most derived interface.

Comment: @HansPassant

"Necessarily that requires knowing what specific interface needs to be marshalled"
Why? The docs clearly state that the pointer is queried for `IMarshal` so from what I understand the implementation can be dynamically used vs statically as you imply. Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Also, `IDispatch` pointers can be queried for interfaces and can be downcasted to those interfaces, so what would be the usecase for a custom `IMarshal` impelmentation?

Comment: What happens undercover can be very complex and very depends on your specific implementation and context. Use the IID of the interface you're passing around, whatever it derives from, with Ro­Get­Agile­Reference for Windows 8+ https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151020-00/?p=91321 or this for earlier https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151021-00/?p=91311 PS: having to marshal COM objects between threads can be a bad smell.

Comment: Never, *never* cast an interface pointer.  It **must** be done with QueryInterface().  Look at the IMarshal functions, note the REFIID that is passed.  That came from the CoMarshalInterface() call.

Comment: `IID` is absolutely required because the API marshals and unmarshals specific interface, not some generic one. You might see no difference if your code QIs then anyway and/or does late binding and hence no big difference between IDispatch descendants for the proxy caller. Yet the API has to be the way it is.

Comment: The `IID` actually does not matter, provided that it's implemented by the coclass. If you unmarshal a proxy to `IDispatch` in a different thread and `QI` for `IMyCustomInterface` the original proxy will create a second proxy to `IMyCustomInterface` and vice versa. So it doesn't matter if you begin with (CoUnmarshalInterface) `IDispatch` or your most derived interface (provided that it's implemented on the coclass). The `[in] REFIID riid, [out] LPVOID *ppv` pair of parameters is a design pattern with every COM function which returns interfaces (it has to know which exact interface to return).